# How can I get a Fuji Xerox M225 dw scanner to be detected?

Tags: networking, scanner

I have a **Fuji Xerox DocuPrint M225 dw** printer/scanner, that's connected to the same wifi network as my Ubuntu 17.04 system, as well as physically connected via USB.

Simple Scan cannot see it (I get the "No scanners detected" banner). It's visible via Avahi though:

```
~ • avahi-browse -a
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 FX DocuPrint M225 dw                          Internet Printer     local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 FX DocuPrint M225 dw                          _scanner._tcp        local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 FX DocuPrint M225 dw                          PDL Printer          local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 FX DocuPrint M225 dw                          UNIX Printer         local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 FX DocuPrint M225 dw                          Web Site             local
```

And `sane-find-scanner` can see the USB but not the network interface:

```
~ • sudo sane-find-scanner
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x138a, product=0x0017) at libusb:001:006
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0550 [FX], product=0x0190 [DocuPrint]) at libusb:001:002
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

But `scanimage -L` can't see anything:

```
~ • SANE_DEBUG_NET=128 scanimage -L
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of net to 128.
[net] sane_init: authorize != null, version_code != null
[net] sane_init: SANE net backend version 1.0.14 (AF-indep+IPv6) from sane-backends 1.0.27git
[net] sane_init: Client has little endian byte order
[net] sane_init: searching for config file
[net] net_avahi_browse_callback: CACHE_EXHAUSTED
[net] sane_init: done reading config
[net] sane_init: evaluating environment variable SANE_NET_HOSTS
[net] sane_init: evaluating environment variable SANE_NET_TIMEOUT
[net] sane_init: done
[net] sane_get_devices: local_only = 0
[net] sane_get_devices: finished (0 devices)
[net] net_avahi_browse_callback: ALL_FOR_NOW

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
[net] sane_exit: exiting
[net] net_avahi_cleanup: stopping thread
[net] net_avahi_cleanup: done
[net] sane_exit: finished.
```

I've tried installing the `libsane*-dev` packages and upgrading to the packages in the [`rolfbensch/sane-git`](https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git) PPA, rebooting each time. No change in detection. I've confirmed that `net` is present and uncommented in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`.

What else can I try?

Comment: talk directly to the sane development folks: join their mailing list http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/sane-devel and you have the hardware; they have the expertise; see if they can help you; I cannot see the vendor ID **0x0550** in the sane lists anywhere but I may be missing something: I do wonder if you write a file in udev rules so it is recognised; and edit the xerox file in /etc/sane.d/ and list the ID there also;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked on the mailing list](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/sane-devel/2017-August/035540.html). Alas, there's not really anything that can be done, since there's almost no public information that the SANE developers can use to write a driver for this scanner:

> It's even possible it's based on a re-badged
>   Brother engine.  Unfortunately there's apparently little-to-no support
>   in SANE for any Brother scanners.  It may be that there's simply
>   no information publicly available to allow a driver to be written for
>   these.  Manufacturers often don't bother to document the protocols;
>   they simply ship a Windows-compatible driver or application, declare
>   victory, and leave for home.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I also buy **Fuji Xerox DocuPrint M225 dw** and I have problems about scanner driver installation on my linux laptop too (Ubuntu 14.04). I have tried with several methods to install it. Fortunately, I've found the way to make it works.

I have installed **Fuji Xerox DocuPrint M225 dw** driver using **Brother DCP-L2540DW** driver. Followed by these steps.

1. Connect the scanner to the network and setup the IP address for it. For example 172.18.9.103
2. Download and install driver [`brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb`](http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb) or [`brscan4-0.4.2-1.i386.deb`](http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan4-0.4.2-1.i386.deb). For this example using the 64bit version.

   `$ wget http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb`

   `$ sudo dpkg -i brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb`
3. Add network scanner with this command.

   `$ brsaneconfig4 -a \
   name=FX-DocuPrint-M225-dw \
   model=DCP-L2540DW \
   ip=172.18.9.103`
4. The configurations are stored in `/opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg`
5. Make sure `brother4` is in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` and uncomment.
6. Open `simple-scan`. The title `Brother *FX-DocuPrint-M225-dw` should be displayed in `Scan Source`.

[image: Scan Source Screenshot]

7. For example. I scan my A4 handwriting.

[image: Example Scan Screenshot]

Comment: this worked for me, thanks! It'd be nice if USB scanning was an option, but I'll take what I can get

Comment: Hmm, I followed all the instructions, I can connect to the device via web browser, but Simple Scan doesn't see it. No firewall either.

Comment: link to device support page with newer versions of the drivers: https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpl2540dw_us_as&os=128

Comment: this 99% worked for me: the only problem is that photo scans are b&w not color (in high res, though). I've gone through all simple-scan settings (i think) and couldn't find a way to  switch it: any hints?

Comment: ok, that's very funny: after i set BRIGHTNESS to max it started to scan in color. LOLz :D
also xsane works normally: you can switch between color and b&w scanning there normally without strange tricks like in simple-scan.

Comment: btw: how on earth have you figured out that a driver for a completely different, seemingly random other device works for this one?  this seems like some voodoo black magic or at least a serious hacking ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a Fuji Xerox DocuPrint M225 dw and had a problem with getting the scanner to work.  I followed steps 1, 2, 3 and 4 above but step 5 was not satisfied.  The scanner could be seen but not connected.  I found the page for the Brother drivers http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html.  I guessed the FX printer was similar to the Brother MFC-1810.  Found the brscan 64bit file was already installed.  I installed the scan-key-tool 64bit file.  I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 so it was pretty easy.  After switching off the printer and switching it back on it scanned fine.  This is with a usb connection.  Haven't tried wifi yet.  thanks Phitak.